# How do you find the sum of certain elements in an array in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get `sumSection` to summarize the element that a runner calls on but am unsure on how to do it?

```
package com.company;

public class processser
{
    //instance variables and constructors could be present, but are not necessary

    //sumSection will return the sum of the numbers
    //from start to stop, not including stop
    public static int sumSection(int[] numArray, int start, int stop)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        {
            for (int i : numArray)
                sum += i;
        }
        return sum ;
    }

    //countVal will return a count of how many times val is present in numArray
    public static int countVal(int[] numArray, int val)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int item : numArray)
        {
            if (item == val)
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Here is the runner:

```
package com.company;

import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] theRay = {2,4,6,8,10,12,8,16,8,20,8,4,6,2,2};

        out.println("Original array : "+ Arrays.toString(theRay));

        out.println("Sum of 0-3: " + processser.sumSection(theRay, 0, 3));

    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the sum of the positions in my array 0-3. I've tried all I know in java but don't understand how to get the sum of 0-3 in the array using `sumSection`

Comment: If you used `List`s instead of arrays, you could simply call `List.subList()` to get a `List` view containing only the elements you want to sum.

Comment: Not sure why no one has posted a link to for and foreach loops usage/structures

Answer (score 3):

You could use Java 8 Streams:

```
static int sumSection(int[] numArray, int start, int stop) {
    return IntStream.range(start, stop).map(i -> numArray[i]).sum();
}
```

This goes from `start` to `stop` (exclusive), so if you have:

```
int[] theRay = {2,4,6,8,10,12,8,16,8,20,8,4,6,2,2};
sumSection(theRay, 0, 3);
```

It would work somewhat like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 3) -> [0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2].map(i -> numArray[i]) -> [2, 4, 6]
[2, 4, 6].sum() -> 12
```

Just be sure that `start < stop` and `stop <= numArray.length` and you should have no problems.

Comment: You could use `Math.min(stop, numArray.length)` in the `.range()` call to avoid needing to check that `stop <= numArray.length`.

Comment: Sure, it could be changed. Though, it's common that methods which work with arrays return an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when appropriate. Often, the caller is responsible for passing the correct arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = start; (i < numArray.length) && (i <= stop); i++) {
    sum += numArray[i];
}
```

Comment: nitpick  `i<=array.length` is potentially an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @gtgaxiola Right, fixed.

Comment: Thank you sensei even if you don't include it in your own answer :)

Comment: Op wanted up to stop (meaning exclusive) so should be `i<stop`

Comment: @BenKnoble I understand otherwise from: `processser.sumSection(theRay, 0, 3)` *"how to get the sum of 0-3 in the array using sumSection"*

Answer (score 1):

You need another type of loop instead of:

```
for (int i : numArray)
```

A better approach would be:

```
int sum = 0;
if(stop <= array.length && start < stop) {
    for(int i = start; i < stop; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: He has a for-each loop here, so you may want to add on another small thing, which is:

sum += numArray[i];

rather than sum+=i , which wouldn't work now that it's the index rather than the value

As for the boundary check, do something like this:

if(numArray != null && start >=0 && start < numArray.length && stop < numArray.length & stop >= start)

though you should likely check that before you even start the loop.